# Is there a way that I can split an excel spreadsheet into different sheets by row value?

Tags: python, excel

I have an excel workbook that contains a report of jobs that we have taken and lists them onto one excel worksheet. I want to split this big worksheet into different smaller worksheets based on the row value in the second column. For example, I would like to have all of the rows with a cell value of "New Jobs" in the second column of the big spreadsheet to be moved to smaller spreadsheet. Currently, this piece of code is capable of reading the spreadsheet and grouping each row into a smaller lists in a big list.

Can I get some suggestions on how to move forward with this project?

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(r"spreadsheet.xlsx")
ws = wb.active

statuses = ["NEW JOB", "DESIGN & AMENDS", "MARKETING", "R&D", "PRE-PRESS", "ON PROOF", "AWAITING ARTWORK", "HARD PROOF", "WAITING PARTS/PAPER", "READY TO PRINT",
                "URGENT", "PRINTING", "COVERS", "MONO", "OVERPRINT", "LAMINATING", "FOIL/SPOT GLOSS", "BINDING", "DIE CUTTING", "CREASING", "DRILLING", "TRIM", "FINISHING/PACKING",
                "DATA DUPLICATING", "OUTSOURCED", "WAITING COLLECTION", "DISPATCH SAME DAY", "DISPATCH NEXT DAY", "DISPATCH PDS", "DISPATCH POST", "DISPATCHED", "ON HOLD/WAITING INSTRUCTION",
                "COMPLETED & INVOICED", "CANCELLED", "COMPLETED"]

Dictionary = {i: " " for i in statuses} #where the,' ', is, we would like to put in the corresponding list to each key. 


#print(Dictionary)
press = []

for row in ws.rows:
    
    for j in range(0,1):
        
        for k in range(0,35):
            
            if row[1].value == statuses[k]:
                
                for l in range(0,8):
                    
                    press.append(row[l].value)
                    
                    
print(press)

chunk_size = 8
chunked_list = [press[i:i + 8] for i in range(0, len(press), 8)]
print(chunked_list)
```

Currently, this piece of code is capable of reading the spreadsheet and grouping each row into a smaller lists in a big list.

Can I get some suggestions on how to move forward with this project?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward way of resolving this is grouping rows of desired values and writing them off on a new excel workbook using the xlsxwriter python library.